What is the recommended wire for a new 60Amp subpanel in a residential home
I would like to install a new subpanel in my attached garage in Texas. I plan to install a 100 Amp panel with a 60 Amp breaker in the main, which should be plenty adequate for the wood working tools I plan to run. The run is about 50' through my attic, including the rise from the main and the drop to the sub. What type of wire can I run that does not require conduit in the attic? Is 2-2-2-4 Al the recommended size?

Conduit in the attic is actually a good thing based on any number of gnawed cables I've seen when remodeling. Yeah, sure, your house doesn't have any rodents at any time, they wouldn't dare, you've never seen one, etc...

The answer is in an ampacity table:

6 AWG copper wires in conduit or SE cable
4 AWG copper NM cable
4 AWG aluminum wires in conduit or SE cable

At these sizes, aluminum is generally much less expensive than copper. Even jurisdictions that prohibit aluminum for branch wiring allow it for subpanel wiring. You can use larger wires (smaller # AWG) without any problem, as long as they will fit on your breaker, so 2/2/2/4 aluminum is generally a good choice. As 2/2/2/4 aluminum is good for up to 90A, that will also allow for future upgrade of the feed breaker if you need to add some more power for EV charging or other uses.
Note that whether at 60A or 90A or any other size, you should do a Load Calculation on your main panel/service to make sure you can supply the desired amount of power to the subpanel. A 200A service might be able to easily spare an extra 60A, or it could already be nearly full without you realizing it. A lot depends on the type of HVAC, size of the house and whether major appliances (e.g., oven, cooktop, water heater, dryer) are electric or gas.

What are the cable tray requirements for an attic run of SER cable? What I have found is not that clear.

"cable tray" is not the term usually used (in my experience) in residential wiring. Basically you use either a cable type that is approved (e.g., 2/2/2/4 Aluminum SER) or you use individual wires in an approved conduit type (typically metal or PVC - but has to be an actual conduit type - metal or PVC water pipe may be practically up the task but is not approved).
